# Limit of this function at 0+

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Let $$f(x):=  x\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \exp((-\log x)^{\alpha}) .$$

where $\alpha$ is fixed.

My question is, what is the limit $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x)$ ?

This is easily shown to be $\infty$ for $\alpha \in [1,\infty)$, and also it's easy to see that this limit is $0$ for $\alpha \in (-\infty,0].$

So I am interested in the range $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $$y = -\log x = \log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ to get $$\begin{align}x\log(\frac{1}{x})\exp((-\log x)^\alpha)=y\exp(-y+y^\alpha) \\ = \frac{y}{\exp(y-y^{\alpha})}\end{align}$$ Then since $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}y= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (-\log(x))= \infty$$ and numerator and denominator tends to infinity you can apply L'Hospitals rule.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. so the limit for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ according to my calculations is $0$. by the way in your final display I think you mean $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}$.

Comment: yes, you can assume $lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}$.